# How To change "Tags" in wp-admin menu, page title, & posts editor

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In the wp-admin Wordpress backend under the Posts menu there are default menus for Category and Tags.  I want rename "Tags" something else.  I already know how to do it in the menu, but how do you change it where it displays as a title on the Tags page as well as in the right side widget area in the post editor?

Picture illustrates the areas in which the Tag label is displayed and needs to be adjusted..

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yahooo :)
i find out the solution
here is the function . put it in function.php

```
function change_tax_object_label() {
      global $wp_taxonomies;
      $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels;
      $labels->name = __('Keywords', 'framework');
      $labels->singular_name = __('Keywords', 'framework');
      $labels->search_items = __('Search Keywords', 'framework');
      $labels->all_items = __('Keywords', 'framework');
      $labels->separate_items_with_commas = __('Separate Keywords with commas', 'framework');
      $labels->choose_from_most_used = __('Choose from the most used Keywords', 'framework');
      $labels->popular_items = __('Popular Keywords', 'framework');
      $labels->edit_item = __('Edit Keyword Name', 'framework');
      $labels->view_item = __('View Keyword Name', 'framework');
      $labels->update_item = __('Update Keyword Name', 'framework');
      $labels->add_new_item = __('Add Your Keyword Name', 'framework');
      $labels->new_item_name = __('Your New Keywords Name', 'framework');
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'change_tax_object_label' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full entries to edit for tag label :

```
function change_tax_object_label() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels;
    $labels->name = "Types";
    $labels->singular_name = "Types";
    $labels->search_items = "Rechercher types";
    $labels->all_items = "Types";
    $labels->separate_items_with_commas = "Séparer les types par des point-virgules \";\"";
    $labels->choose_from_most_used = "Choisir parmis les types les plus utilisés";
    $labels->popular_items = "Types populaires";
    $labels->edit_item = "Éditer le type";
    $labels->view_item = "Voir le type";
    $labels->update_item = "Modifier le type";
    $labels->add_new_item = "Ajouter un nouveau type";
    $labels->new_item_name = "Nouveau type";
    $labels->add_or_remove_items = "Ajouter ou retirer des types";
    $labels->not_found = "Aucun type trouvé.";
    $labels->no_terms = "Aucun type";
    $labels->items_list_navigation = "Navigation de la liste des types";
    $labels->items_list = "Liste des types";
    $labels->back_to_items = "← Retour aux types";
    $labels->menu_name = "Types";
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_tax_object_label' );
```

Answer (score 0):

and to change in menu

```
<?php

add_action('init', 'renameTags');

function renameTags() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $cat = $wp_taxonomies['post_tag'];
    $cat->label = __('Keyword ', 'theme-slug');
    $cat->labels->singular_name = __('Keyword ', 'theme-slug');
    $cat->labels->name = $cat->label;
    $cat->labels->menu_name = $cat->label;
}
```